# Best approach to populate DynamoDb table

Tags: json, csv, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

Please keep in mind this is a open question and I am not looking for a specific answer but just approaches and routes I can take.

Essentially I am getting a csv file from my aws s3 bucket. I am able to get it successfully using

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());        
S3Object object = s3Client.getObject(
                  new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key));
```

Now I want to populate a dynamodb  table using this JSON file.

I was confused as i found all sorts of stuff online.

Here is one [suggestion](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectUsingJava.html) - This approach is however only reading the file it is not inserting anything to the dynamodb table.

Here is another [suggestion](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/GettingStarted.Java.02.html) - This approach is lot closer to what i am looking for , it is populating a table from a JSON file.

However i was wondering is there a generic way to ready any json file and populate a dynamodb table based on that ? Also for my case what approach is the best?

**Since i originally asked the question I did more work.**

**What I have done so far**

I have a csv file sitting in s3 that looks like this

```
name,position,points,assists,rebounds
Lebron James,SF,41,12,11
Kyrie Irving,PG,41,7,5
Stephen Curry,PG,29,8,4
Klay Thompson,SG,31,5,5
```

I am able to sucessfully pick it up as a s3object doing the following

```
AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(/**new ProfileCredentialsProvider()*/); 
    S3Object object = s3client.getObject(
            new GetObjectRequest("lambda-function-bucket-blah-blah", "nba.json"));
            InputStream objectData = object.getObjectContent();
```

Now I want to insert this in to my dynamodb table so i am attempting the following.

```
AmazonDynamoDBClient dbClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
dbClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_BLAH_1));

DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(dbClient); 
//DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client); 
Table table = dynamoDB.getTable("MyTable");
```

//after this point i have tried many json parsers etc and did  table.put(item) etc but nothing has worked. I would appreciate kind help

Comment: Your links are about complementary things, both of which seem to be needed for your problem.
A "best" approach is hard to tell without much more context. In any case, I don't see why you couldn't start with using those two snippets as a starting point.

Comment: @MBW i can definitely read from the file at this point but i am not able to insert anything in the table.

Comment: @MBW also the issue with second approach is that is using a local file, i have s3object which i want to populate my table from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For CSV parsing, you can use plain reader as your file looks quite simple

```
    AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(/**new ProfileCredentialsProvider()*/); 
    S3Object object = s3client.getObject(
                new GetObjectRequest("lambda-function-bucket-blah-blah", "nba.json"));
    InputStream objectData = object.getObjectContent();

    AmazonDynamoDBClient dbClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
    dbClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_BLAH_1));

    DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(dbClient); 
    //DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client); 
    Table table = dynamoDB.getTable("MyTable"); 

    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(objectData, "UTF-8"));

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            // use comma as separator
            String[] elements = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

            try {
                table.putItem(new Item()
                    .withPrimaryKey("name", elements[0])
                    .withString("position", elements[1])
                    .withInt("points", elements[2])
                    .....);

                System.out.println("PutItem succeeded: " + elements[0]);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Unable to add user: " + elements);
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                break;
            }

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Depending the complexity of your CSV, you can use 3rd party libraries like [Apache CSV Parser](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html) or [open CSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)

I leave the original answer for parsing JSon

I would use the [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) library and following your code do the following

```
    AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(/**new ProfileCredentialsProvider()*/); 
    S3Object object = s3client.getObject(
                new GetObjectRequest("lambda-function-bucket-blah-blah", "nba.json"));
    InputStream objectData = object.getObjectContent();

    AmazonDynamoDBClient dbClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
    dbClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_BLAH_1));

    DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(dbClient); 
    //DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client); 
    Table table = dynamoDB.getTable("MyTable"); 

    JsonParser parser = new JsonFactory()
        .createParser(objectData);

    JsonNode rootNode = new ObjectMapper().readTree(parser);
    Iterator<JsonNode> iter = rootNode.iterator();

    ObjectNode currentNode;

    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        currentNode = (ObjectNode) iter.next();

        String lastName  = currentNode.path("lastName").asText();
        String firstName = currentNode.path("firstName").asText();
        int minutes      = currentNode.path("minutes").asInt();
        // read all attributes from your JSon file

        try {
            table.putItem(new Item()
                .withPrimaryKey("lastName", lastName, "firstName", firstName)
                .withInt("minutes", minutes));

            System.out.println("PutItem succeeded: " + lastName + " " + firstName);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Unable to add user: " + lastName + " " + firstName);
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            break;
        }
    }
    parser.close();
```

Inserting the records in your table will depend of your schema, I just put an arbitrary example, but anyway this will get you the reading of your file and the way to insert into the dynamoDB table

As you talked about the different approaches, another possibility is to setup a [AWS Pipeline](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-importexport-ddb-part1.html)

Comment: This makes a little sense. is it possible to maybe just show in the same code how i can create a table with that schema or can i create a table manually to allow this insertion?

Comment: I am maybe old school but usually prefer to create schema from the console, here is the [doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/JavaDocumentAPIWorkingWithTables.html) to create tables from Java code, I did not try such code, will take me some time to test but you if you have any issue, please address it should work ok

Comment: i apologize for this but i was wondering if you can show me how to achieve the same thing given data is in csv format and not JSON. i apologize

Comment: Thank you, i just had a question. what if you do not know the column is a string or int because you can't tell by just looking at column name what type it is and in your code you are explicitly assuming that it is a string or a INT.

Comment: interesting, I would probably try to read from `table.getKeySchema()` which will return the list of [element](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/model/KeySchemaElement.html) and you can get element name and type

Comment: Hey, i posted a new question around this maybe you can help me with this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39103094/parsing-a-csv-file-to-populate-database