# Parsing a csv file to populate database

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

Given I have a csv file such as this

```
str_name,int_points,int_bonus
joe,2,5
Moe,10,15
Carlos,25,60
```

I can have csv file with x number of columns and y number of rows so i am trying to develop a generic method to parse it and populate data in to dynamodb table.

In order to populate the dynamodb table i would do something like this

```
String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(objectData, "UTF-8"));

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            // use comma as separator
            String[] elements = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

            try {
                table.putItem(new Item()
                    .withPrimaryKey("name", elements[0])
                    .withInt("points", elements[1])
                    .withInt("bonus", elements[2])
                    .....);

                System.out.println("PutItem succeeded: " + elements[0]);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Unable to add user: " + elements);
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                break;
            }

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However i would not always know wether i am inserting a int or a string, it is depenedent on the csv file so i was kinda lost on how to create a generic function which would read the first line of my csv file and take advantage of prefix which indicates if the particular column is a int or a string.

Comment: Can't you dictate what format your CSV file will have?

Comment: I would use a API something like opencsv. When you parse the CSV file you will get a String[] of String[] which will help you to in this case.

Comment: @dsp_user my csv file will be exactly like the sample i posted above..except ofcourse it will have more columns and rows..

Comment: When you parse your csv file you'll have a String[] for every row in your file. Provided that you know the positions of int and strings, it should be simple to persist those values to the DB. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @dsp_user that i understand but how will i use that to my method which inserts data  if you look at my table.putItem , and everything following that would have to change based on how many columns and what types are.  i would love it if you can show an example of how you would do this maybe i am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Just store labels (first row) and then while iterating over row values, decide based on label what method to call. If you are not against bringing some external dependencies I advise you to use some external csv reader , e.g. 
[SuperCsv](http://super-csv.github.io/super-csv/index.html)
Using this library you can for example read each row as a Map(label->val) then iterate over entries and based on labels prefix update your db with correct method. Or just read header and then do the same reading each row as a list.

Example :

This is of course very crude and I would probably refactor it somehow (e.g. have a list of processors for each column instead of ugly switch)
but it shows you the idea

```
        List<String> labels = new ArrayList<>();//store first row here
        List<String> elements = new ArrayList<>();//currently processed line here
        Item item = new Item();
        for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
            String label = labels.get(i);
            switch (getTypePrefix(label)){
                case "int":
                    item = item.withInt(getName(label),elements.get(i));
                    break;
                case "str":
                    item = item.withString(getName(label),elements.get(i));
                    break;
                default:
                    //sth
                    break;
            }
        }
        table.putItem(item);
```

Comment: The issue is not with reading rows but how to insert data after i have read the rows and columns..an example would be appreciated.

Comment: added simple example

Answer (score 0):

OK, I can't post this as a comment so I wrote  a simple example. Note that I'm not familiar with that Amazon API you're using but you should get the idea how I'd go about it (I've basically rewritten your code)

```
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = ",";

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(objectData, "UTF-8"));

     String[]  colNames = br.readLine().split(cvsSplitBy);      //first line just to get the column names
     while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String currColumnName = colNames.get(i);
        // use comma as separator
        String[] elements = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
        boolean isInt ;
        for (int i = 0; i < elements.length;i++){

        try {
            try{
            int iVal = new Integer(elements[i]);
            isInt = true;
            }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            //process exception
            isInt = false;
            }
            if(isInt){
            table.putItem.(new Item().withInt(currColumnName,iVal));
            }else{
            table.putItem.(new Item().withString(currColumnName),elements[i])); //don't even know whether there is a withString method
            }

            System.out.println("PutItem succeeded: " + elements[i]);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Unable to add user: " + elements);
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            break;
        }
        }

    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This example assumes that your first row contains the column names as stored in the DB. You don't have to write anywhere whether they an int or a String because there is a check in the program (granted this is not the most efficient way to do this and you may write something better, perhaps what Molok has suggested)